# How to choose specific value in select box with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

here's a fiddle of what i've got:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LHBL/1/

How can I reset the second dropdown once its been repopulated to choose either the first item or one that I designate from elsewhere?

Example:

1. User looks at 'abc' '5'
2. User changes to  'def' -> second select should choose  value =='20' || first option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it choose a new option by setting `selectedEvent` right after you set the new `events` list. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/3LHBL/2/

Setting the first option would be done similarly: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/3LHBL/3/